# Magento - catalog_product_save_after: Check if product has been saved

Tags: magento, observers

I am currently trying to save a product with attributes that I have built, and it's working fine. I have also set up my code to call the catalog_product_save_after function on my observer, as shown below:

```
class Package_MyModule_Model_Observer
{ 
    public function catalog_product_save_after($observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        //Do stuff here
    }
}
```

In this line of code here, is there a way to detect whether the product has already been saved (i.e. no error messages were shown)? Because I need to update some values in the database when the product is saved successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly this gets called after product is saved successfully, but to be sure you can hook into

```
catalog_product_save_commit_after
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with this. I've tried it with errors on the product details and I got it working. :)